# Perform function within dplyr::mutate and ignore missing values

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I am struggling to find a solution to what should be (and probably is) an easy problem.

Given the following data (code below):

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
      id datetime           
   <dbl> <dttm>             
 1     1 NA                 
 2     2 2023-01-16 10:00:00
 3     3 NA                 
 4     4 2023-01-18 20:00:00
 5     5 2023-01-28 21:00:00
 6     6 2023-01-17 19:00:00
 7     7 NA                 
 8     8 2023-01-16 04:00:00
 9     9 2023-01-15 06:00:00
10    10 2023-01-13 21:00:00
```

I would like to extract the hour from a POSIXct vector to a new variable, but missing values are causing me an issue.

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      id datetime            hour           
   <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>
 1     1 NA                  NA
 2     2 2023-01-16 10:00:00 10
 3     3 NA                  NA
 4     4 2023-01-18 20:00:00 20
 5     5 2023-01-28 21:00:00 21
 6     6 2023-01-17 19:00:00 19
 7     7 NA                  NA
 8     8 2023-01-16 04:00:00 4
 9     9 2023-01-15 06:00:00 6
10    10 2023-01-13 21:00:00 21
```

I have tried various versions of if_else or case_when to manage the missing values, but keep getting an error. My current version throws the error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `hour = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error in `map_chr()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! Result must be length 1, not 0.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Suggesting it is still including missing values in the FALSE part of the if_else.

Reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  id = seq(1, 10, 1),
  datetime = sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2023/1/1"), as.POSIXct("2023/1/31"), by = "hour"), 10)
)
dat[c(1, 3, 7), 2] <- NA

dat

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    hour = if_else(
      is.na(datetime),
      NA,
      datetime %>% str_split(" ") %>% map_chr(2) %>% hms() %>% hour()
      )
    )
```

Comment: lubridate is your friend, try: `mutate(dat, hour = lubridate::hour(datetime) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lubridate::hour()` is your friend here...

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat <- tibble(
  id = seq(1, 10, 1),
  datetime = sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2023/1/1"), as.POSIXct("2023/1/31"), by = "hour"), 10)
)
dat[c(1, 3, 7), 2] <- NA


mutate(dat, hour = lubridate::hour(datetime) )
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>       id datetime             hour
#>    <dbl> <dttm>              <int>
#>  1     1 NA                     NA
#>  2     2 2023-01-11 05:00:00     5
#>  3     3 NA                     NA
#>  4     4 2023-01-05 15:00:00    15
#>  5     5 2023-01-04 00:00:00     0
#>  6     6 2023-01-26 06:00:00     6
#>  7     7 NA                     NA
#>  8     8 2023-01-12 21:00:00    21
#>  9     9 2023-01-20 12:00:00    12
#> 10    10 2023-01-05 04:00:00     4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: A simple solution indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is likely caused by the use of hms(). hms() is more suited for working with durations, not with timestamps or datetime objects, which you have. The best function to solve this problem will be using the hour() function from the lubridate package to extract the hour from the datetime values in your datetime column, like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  id = seq(1, 10, 1),
  datetime = sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2023/1/1"), as.POSIXct("2023/1/31"), by = "hour"), 10)
)

dat[c(1, 3, 7), 2] <- NA


dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    hour = if_else(
      is.na(datetime),
      NA,
      lubridate::hour(datetime)
    )
  )

dat
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>       id datetime             hour
#>    <dbl> <dttm>              <int>
#>  1     1 NA                     NA
#>  2     2 2023-01-15 22:00:00    22
#>  3     3 NA                     NA
#>  4     4 2023-01-02 19:00:00    19
#>  5     5 2023-01-13 06:00:00     6
#>  6     6 2023-01-18 00:00:00     0
#>  7     7 NA                     NA
#>  8     8 2023-01-21 00:00:00     0
#>  9     9 2023-01-14 10:00:00    10
#> 10    10 2023-01-13 17:00:00    17
```

Alternatively, you can use a case_when function in mutate instead of ifelse to modify it like this while keeping all NA values intact in the new column

```
dat <- tibble(
  id = seq(1, 10, 1),
  datetime = sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2023/1/1"), as.POSIXct("2023/1/31"), by = "hour"), 10)
)
dat[c(1, 3, 7), 2] <- NA

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    hour = case_when(
      is.na(datetime) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ datetime %>% lubridate::hour()
    )
  )
```